# Setup openssh to start when the computer boots

Tags: server, ssh, openssh, headless, sshd

I have a headless server and I was wondering if it is possible to start openssh without logging in. It would start without the need for a password, so I wouldn't have to plug in a monitor every time I rebooted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not allowed to comment yet but I was going to ask how you installed it
Because if you installed openssh with `apt-get install openssh-server` then it should start automatically on boot even without a working network.

Comment: That is how I installed it. I just didn't know it started on boot.

Comment: The correct command should: **`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`** Yes (by default) this starts on boot; but it can be disabled.

Comment: I was assuming root @david6